# How to activate Content Assist - Java Proposals

Tags: eclipse-jdt

I have installed eclipse in Ubuntu 12.10. After working for a few days, I created my first CDT C++ project and stay there for while. Now when I go back to my Java project I found that when I type in a variable name and press "." nothing appears.

However, I can bring the context menu back by select "Edit" -> "Content assit" -> "Java Proposals". The problem is it is not convenient at all. When Click "Default Proposals" an empty context menu with "No Default proposal" appears. I have also confirmed that the right aspect "Java" is being activated.

How to return back to the original status (the Java proposals menu brings by default)?

Eclipse Platform version is 3.7.0.I20120502-2000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just fixed this problem by scanning all preferences options. However it is still not explain why it was disappeared because I didn't change anything there.

In "Preferences" dialog choose "Java" -> "Editor" -> "Content Assist" -> "Advanced", in my case the top list box there are some check box have not checked, including "Java Proposals". The problem has been fixed by check that box and click "OK" button.

I will leave this answer here for a while before I mark it as right, to hear better advices.

Comment: I also had this issue on a clean install of `Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627` I'm glad you posted your solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Access Content Assist**
you can type and search "Java Proposal" in "quick access", to find the "content assist" menu

Ctrl + 3 ==>Go to "Quick Access" menu
Type and search "Java Proposals"
Check that Bok and Click ok...

[searching content assist through Quick Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsoUA.png)